# Eos and Scatter

Tags: eosjs, scatter

When using scatter, what does `Eos` refer to when making this call?

`const eos = scatter.eos( network, Eos, eosOptions );`

Docs:
https://get-scatter.com/docs/dev/signature-providers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the eosjs object that you have in the browser as Scatter requires it to be present to be able to sign EOS transactions. See here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs

```
Eos = require('eosjs')
```

The Scatter documentations are pretty new and are really terse. This should be expanded in the documentation of scatter.